# what is the result of ( 4 > + 4 )?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need the explanation of this syntax , does this mean that (+4) is the same as (4) ? I have tried many other operands and it completely works as if I disregarded the plus sign before the number .

Comment: yes, `+4` is the same as `4`.

Comment: The `+` in Python works the same as the `+` in mathematics.

Comment: *I have tried many other operands and it completely works as if I disregarded the plus sign before the number*, did that not answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

Would you be confused by

```
4 > -4
```

The only difference between that and

```
4 > +4
```

is a different unary operator

Answer (score 3):

The `+` in `+4` is the [unary plus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations):

> The unary `+` (plus) operator yields its numeric argument unchanged.

So yes, because `4` is a number (an `int`), `+4` means just the same thing as `4`, as the operator returns the number unchanged.

The operator exists as a counterpart to the [`-` unary minus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#unary-arithmetic-and-bitwise-operations):

```
4 > -4
```

Custom classes could override it using the [`__pos__()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__pos__), making it possible to return custom results.

Answer (score 2):

*(In addition to the points pointed out by the other answers ...)*

The comparison operations in Python [have lower precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) than the `positive` unary operator (`+operand`):

> Unlike C, all comparison operations in Python have the same priority,
>   *which is lower than that of any arithmetic, shifting or bitwise
>   operation*.

This means that the unary plus operator applied to its operand will be evaluated prior to the comparison operator, and `+4` will result in simply just `4` prior the unary comparison operation even starting.

```
4 < +4
4 < (+4)
4 < 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're effectively the same. The unary `+` operator in `+4` is applied to the `4` and `4` is the result.

Answer (score 0):

To check if your variables are the same type them into your interpreter with the == operator between them. If they are the same, this will return True.

```
>>> 4 == +4
True
```

This may seem daft or obvious in this case, but when working with more complex variables it can be more useful.